# JS/Jquery way to determine if the user entered page from another site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to write a script that would launch a modal if the user enters a page from any external link. I am assuming the document.referrer is the way to do it, but not familiar enough with JS as to how to implement it in an "if" conditional. Any suggestions are appreciated.

I'm assuming it would look something like this?

```
if (document.referrer !== window.location.hostname) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to check if the user entered a page from an external link, you can parse the `document.referrer` to get just the hostname, and compare that with `window.location.hostname`:

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = document.referrer;
var isExternallyReferred = document.referrer.length > 0 && parser.hostname !== window.location.hostname;

if (isExternallyReferred) {
  // launch modal
}
```

Comment: where would this error be from? Uncaught SyntaxError: "Unexpected token ="

Comment: oops typo! have edited the answer to remove the extra `=` from the `!==` conditional

Comment: so i just added alerts to this see: https://jsfiddle.net/fg83Lx4p/ however I get the correct alert when simply refreshing the page, however when i click on the link from fiddle, I dont get an alert...Maybe I am taking the wrong approach to this?

Comment: also had to check that referrer was set, have updated